# How to change the font in Sublime text to `Fixed Semicondensed`?

Tags: fonts, sublimetext3

I would like to set `"font_face": "Courier New"` to `"font_face": "Fixed SemiCondensed"`, to match my terminal. However, when I do that, it defaults to the native SublimeText font (whatever it is). If I just write `"font_face": "Fixed"`, it correctly picks "Fixed" but it's not "condensed".

`fc-list` gives me `Fixed:style=SemiCondensed` as the font info. However, I've not been able to put them in the name or in the `"font_options"` part.

Any ideas?

Comment: This might be something you also need to file on https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core

Comment: I suspect that Sublime can only match fonts based on the name(s) they export and not on the properties per se. In the case of the `Fixed` font (at least on my system), it appears multiple times with the same name but different styles, so Sublime treats them all the same.

Comment: If sublime allows you to directly provide a font path, you may solve your problems. But it seems that there is no such function currently.